# Test for const behavior with googletest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm using google test to write some unit tests for a container class with iterators. I'd like to create a test that makes sure my `const_iterator` is properly `const`: namely, that I can't assign to it

```
MyContainer<MyType>::const_iterator cItr = MyContainerInstance.cbegin();
*cItr = MyType();    // this should fail.
```

Obviously this will fail to compile (IFF it's coded properly), but is there some way to use google test to leave some kind of check like this in the unit test? Or some way without google test that doesn't require integrating yet another library?

Comment: Can you use C++11? You might want to check out [type_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_const/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it is possible to detect if an iterator is a constant iterator, but it's trickier than I initially thought.

Keep in mind, you don't need an actual instance of your constant iterator, since all you're doing is type-checking:

```
// Include <type_traits> somewhere

typedef MyContainer<MyType>::const_iterator it;
typedef std::iterator_traits<it>::pointer ptr;
typedef std::remove_pointer<ptr>::type iterator_type;
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_const<iterator_type>::value;
// This'll print a 0 or 1 indicating if your iterator is const or not.
```

And then you can check in the usual way in gtest with:

```
EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_const<iterator_type>::value);
```

Free advice: I think it's best to let your compiler check this for you by just writing a test that'll fail to compile if it violates const correctness.

You can test this with `std::vector`:

```
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator c_it;
typedef std::iterator_traits<c_it>::pointer c_ptr;
typedef std::remove_pointer<c_ptr>::type c_iterator_type;
EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_const<c_iterator_type>::value);

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator it;
typedef std::iterator_traits<it>::pointer ptr;
typedef std::remove_pointer<ptr>::type iterator_type;
EXPECT_FALSE(std::is_const<iterator_type>::value);
```

This should both compile and pass.

Comment: The easiest way I found was to `remove_reference` and `decltype` an instance as such: `EXPECT_TRUE(std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*cItr)>::type>::value);`

Comment: I appreciate the advice, it is kinda complicated. However I'm always surprised how supporting `const_iterator` is harder than I think, and there have been too many times I tested the const-ness, commented out the test, then reintroduced the problem :P

Comment: That works, but then you're testing a separate thing. You're testing the return type of the function `cbegin`. If you just want to check if the iterator type you declared is correctly const, then I think what I have suffices. These are unit tests though, so why not both? :P